# How do you syncronously free up resources in rollup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollupjs

I am using the rollup bundler.
When the `rollup.config.mjs` file is edited while rollup is active in watch mode, the file is reloaded.
I have a custom rollup plugin that uses a specific port for the entire duration that rollup is running. When the config is reloaded, I need to close the old server using the port so that it is free again.
I attempted using the `closeWatcher` [hook](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development/#closewatcher) for this, but it seems that rollup does not wait for the `closeWatcher` handler to finish before, causing the port to still be in use and the re-execution of the config to fail.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rollup-repro-zyb91y?file=rollup.config.js) is a minimal reproduction on stackblitz.

rollup.config.js:

```js
console.log('Creating Server');
// <Create Server, using port>

function closeWatcher() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('Closing server');
    // <Close Server, freeing port after a short time>
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Server Closed');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'es',
  },
  plugins: [{ closeWatcher }],
  watch: { 
    clearScreen: false,
  },
};
```

Expected output when changing config file:

```
Creating Server
rollup v3.7.5
bundles src/main.js → dist...
created dist in 31ms

[2023-05-13 18:59:10] waiting for changes...

Reloading updated config...
Closing server
Server Closed
Creating Server | <--- !

bundles src/main.js → dist...
created dist in 3ms

[2023-05-13 18:59:15] waiting for changes...
```

Actual output:

```
Creating Server
rollup v3.7.5
bundles src/main.js → dist...
created dist in 31ms

[2023-05-13 18:59:10] waiting for changes...

Reloading updated config...
Creating Server | <--- !
Closing server
Server Closed
bundles src/main.js → dist...
created dist in 3ms

[2023-05-13 18:59:15] waiting for changes...
```

Notice that `Creating Server` is logged before `Server Closed` meaning that the port/resource is not freed yet but already attempted to be claimed again.

How do I force rollup to let me free up resources (like the port) before it tries to re-execute the config file?